# || operator cannot be used in equalsIgnoreCase() method argument?

Tags: java

```
boolean hasTaxes(){
        return !state.equalsIgnoreCase("TX" || "NM" ||"VA" || "AZ" || "AK");
    }
```

In the above code, I got `The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String` error... so does that mean `||` operator cannot be used in `equalsIgnoreCase()` argument?

Comment: 1) It is not applicable between two String operands.

Comment: Please, check the String Java API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: People, it doesn't make sense to downvote this - this is obviously a beginner question and we've all been there once, be nice to others.

Comment: ...it's nice to follow the answers fall in in rapid concession, funny how people rush in to post crap just so that they'd have "first answer" which is completely meaningless in the long run :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `||` operator on a string which doesn't work. Try this instead

```
return !state.equalsIgnoreCase("TX") &&
!state.equalsIgnoreCase("NM" ) &&
!state.equalsIgnoreCase("VA") &&
!state.equalsIgnoreCase("AZ" ) &&
!state.equalsIgnoreCase("AK");
```

You have to use the `||` operator with booleans, which are what are returned by the `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

Comment: this will always return `true`.

Comment: Correct, I just used this as an example to the OP. The correct operator to use here would be `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

`||` expects `boolean` argument both sides, not the `String`, You might want to do

```
state.equalsIgnoreCase("TX") || state.equalsIgnoreCase("NM") || ..
```

If these are the fixed codes against which you might want to check you should put them into Enum and use it like

```
public enum StateCode{
 CA, TX;
}
```

and now

```
TaxableStateCode stateCode = null;
try{
    stateCode = TaxableStateCode .valueOf(stringCode);
} catch(IlligalArgumentException ex){
   //log why it failed and other things you might want to do
}

if(stateCode == null){
  // invalid code was supplied for TaxableStateCode 
}
```

If they are expected to vary over time, then you should put them somewhere in database or configurable properties file, so that you don't have to change the code to apply effect

Comment: @Bohei I +1 your solution, its clearly good, I answer OP's question to make him/her understand whats wrong

Comment: I consider this site an opportunity to not only "solve the problem", but also to teach; giving guidance on code style and always showing "good code". Just because code compiles and executes, doesn't make it "good".

Comment: -1 Wow. I'd *still* reject your latest version, for multiple reasons, but the main one being you have waaay too much code (roughly double what you need), even if you used an enum.

Answer (score 2):

the parameter for equalIgnoreCase() is a String.
"TX" || "NM" ||"VA" || "AZ" || "AK" is not a string hence you will get parameter undefined.
I would recommend to put all of those states in an array and check if the array contains the text rather than using equalIgnoreCase() for each of the states

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support such an idea (`||` is java's logical OR operator), however you can do this:

```
private static List<String> states = Arrays.asList("TX", "NM", "VA", "AZ", "AK");
```

Then in your method:

```
return !states.contains(state.toUpperCase());
```

Which more or less captures your idea.

#### Edited:

I really wanted to keep this simple so I wouldn't scare the OP, but people have chimed in, so here goes...

If you want to increased execution speed, a `HashSet` would be a better choice to use as the collection type, so you would do this:

```
private static Set<String> states = new HashSet(
    Arrays.asList("TX", "NM", "VA", "AZ", "AK"));
```

If you wanted to go completely nuts on style, you could do this:

```
private static final Set<String> STATES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
    new HashSet(Arrays.asList("TX", "NM", "VA", "AZ", "AK")));
```

Comment: A Set would be a little more efficient.

Comment: @JanDvorak It probably does not make a huge difference, but since both approaches involve more or less the same amount of code, I see no reason to go for a list when a set seems more appropriate.

Comment: @assylias a hashSet probably will compute the hash of the `state`. That's not exactly fast. Similarly, a treeSet will reduce the number of comparisons from an average of three to a maximum of three (at best) but also itroduce more branching. Branch misprediction really hurts a modern CPU - never mind the tiny amount of memory an ArrayList takes (especially with capacity=size).

Comment: @JanDvorak Your branching argument is a very valid one indeed. And TreeSet is O(log n) so I have to agree with you.

Comment: @assylias OK - I've added a Set option, with bells and whistles

Comment: @Bohemian You already had my +1 - I like your "completely nuts on style" version ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I've added a Set option, A HashSet would give excellent, scaleable performance (in case more states are added later). Also, the hashCode of a 2-character String (as the parameters would be here) would be pretty fast to calculate.

Comment: I didn't downvote but a point: what if in your code some state may go tax free ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Even though this would in all likelihood *never* happen, you'd simply remove it from the list and recompile. Are you suggesting that states go in and out of tax-ness at runtime, or trying to suggest that a properties file is warranted, because neither is the case.

Comment: @JigarJoshi then you'll be restarting the server anyways.

Comment: Who *else* downvoted, and why? What is "not useful" about this answer? Enlighten me....

Comment: No (if you put in DB), NO if you make it property based then on change you could have something that can trigger property reload

Comment: @JigarJoshi You need to read about [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). Your proposal is a classic case.

Answer (score 0):

`||` applies with `boolean` operands, never `String`s.

You may rephrase your code in a more cleaner way as this:

```
    enum Tax {TX, NM, VA, AZ, AK}

    boolean hasTaxes(String state) {
        for (Tax tax : Tax.values()) {
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(tax.name())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
String states = "@TX@NM@VA@AZ@AK@";
if(noTaxStates.length() ==2 && 
                          states.indexOf("@"+noTaxStates.toUpperCase()+"@") >0){
     //state exist
}
```

Comment: Correct, but not elegant. Sorry, no +1 from me.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I proposed this because if number of states grows, having multiple `||` will not look. In this approach, you just need to insert the new state in the states String. In other words, it's easy to use.

Comment: This is quite...unique way of solving the problem. Wouldn't get through my code review but I'm giving you points on originality.